# Splash Screen & Premise Screen - Android

Tags: android, try-catch, splash-screen

So I've started to make a simple "splash screen" (it's more of an intro screen) for a simple android game I'm making for a mobile programming course. I've since run into problems. I know I'm supposed to use a thread, but my implementation doesn't seem to work. You should be able to get a feel for the effect I'm going for.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

//how long until we go to the next activity
protected int splashTime = 2000; 
private Thread splashThread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    final TextView first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView third = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView fourth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final TextView fifth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView sixth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    final ImageView main_character = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized(this){

                    first.setText("The year is 2048...");

                    wait(splashTime);

                    first.setText("");
                    second.setText("...the Earth's resources have long been depleted");

                    wait(splashTime);

                    second.setText("");
                    third.setText("Attempts have been made to save our home...");

                    wait(splashTime);

                    third.setText("");
                    fourth.setText("...but all has gone awry, trash now rains from the skies");

                    wait(splashTime);

                    fourth.setText("");
                    fifth.setText("Now, only one man can save us, and his name is...");

                    wait(splashTime);

                    fifth.setText("");
                    sixth.setText("The Garbage Man!");
                    main_character.setImageResource(drawable.bobrgb888);

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                finish();

                //start a new activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();

}
```

The problem is that the first textview gets called, along with the first wait() call, but then I get a force close.

Here's my logcat:

```
07-02 19:35:16.241: W/dalvikvm(709): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):     android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a    view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:629)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5521)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2724)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
07-02 19:35:16.250: E/AndroidRuntime(709):  at com.connor.black.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:41)
07-02 19:35:16.420: D/szipinf(709): Initializing inflate state
```

Comment: If you do this on a background thread and not the UI thread it isn't going to have the effect you are looking for. If you don't mind the user not being able to do anything while this intro is happening you probably don't want to do it on another thread. Or you could use AsyncTask, maybe, although that's usually more for like displaying a progress bar while you do some stuff in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used for my SplashScreen:

```
final SplashScreen splash = this;

Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            go = true;
            while (go) {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(splash, MyActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //stop();
                go = false;
            }
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
```

The problem with your splashscreen is that you're using wait() incorrectly. What you're looking for is sleep().

And to touch the UI thread from a worker thread you need to use runOnUiThread(Runnable action) or a handler.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but I'm mainly trying to figure out why I can't seem to call any code after I call the wait() function

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml

You shouldn't use wait() for this purpose. What you want is sleep().

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a thread here you must call start to initiate the thread.  This will in turn call the run() method:

```
splashTread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      ...
    }
};

splashThread.start();
```

Keep in mind that this will run in the background, ie not the UI thread.

Comment: Ok, I've added this and the first textview gets populated, and it seems like the first wait() call runs, but then I get a forceclose. I'll post up my logcat

Comment: Using a thread here may not be the right choice, as you can see from the "the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." message.  Quick (and maybe dirty) solution would be to not use a thread and just call the TextView update code directly within the onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to touch the UI (ie. setting your textviews' texts)

Just above your thread declaration, put in this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then instead of doing `first.setText("bla bla bla");`

do

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    first.setText("bla bla bla");
  }
});
```

You need to do this because a seperate thread cannot touch UI elements. Using the handler basically tells the UI thread to run whatever you pass in.

Comment: I need to create a new Handler for each time I want to change the text?

Comment: No, the handler stays the same, you create the handler object once in the UI thread. Like I said, you can just declare it right above your thread declaration. Or you could make the Handler object a global. What you create every time is a new Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code inside *splashThread* Thread by something like:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        first.setText("The year is 2048...");
        //... The rest of code goes here too.
    }
});
```

That way UI Thread can touch its views perfectly.